# Custom filter to search only specific fields for several keywords

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom filter on an ngrepeat that needs to search a word in specific fields only. I got that working correctly as shown in code below. Problem is that I also need that to work with not only one word, but multi words. So for example if I have an array with word1 and word2, I need at least a match, in any specified fields, for BOTH words.

```
        $scope.mySearch = function (item){
                var searchTerm = "word1"; //Need to be able to search on ["word1","word2"]
                var fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'phone', 'fax', 'category', 'subCat', 'company', 'street', 'zip', 'state', 'city', 'country'];

                for(var i = 0, l = fields.length; i < l; i ++){
                    if(item[fields[i]] && item[fields[i]].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm)!==-1){
                        return true;
                    }
                } return false;
        };
```

This code works with one word, in this example "word1"... how to have it work for an array of words ? I got lost when tried to add another for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation below works for any number of `searchTerms` and any number of `fields` and performs strict comparison (`===`). You can modify it according to your needs.

So, here is the idea:

"*All* **searchTerms** *match (i.e. `allMatch` is true) iff for every* **word** *in `searchTerms` there is some* **field** *(in `fields`) such that the specified `item`'s* **field** *property has a value that equals* **word**."

```
$scope.mySearch = function (item) {
    var searchTerms = ['word1' 'word2'];
    var fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'phone', 'fax'.
                  'category', 'subCat', 'company', 'street', 'zip',
                  'state', 'city', 'country'];

    var allMatch = searchTerms.every(function (word) {
        return fields.some(function (field) {
            return item[field] === word;
        });
    });

    return allMatch;
};
```

<sub>It can be easily modified to use `for-loop`s, but I chose to use Array's **[`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)** and **[`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** methods, because I find the much more declarative.</sub>

Comment: Thanks this works, but it lost the ability to find uncomplete word. For example, if I only type "wor" it won't return all entries that contain "word" for example. In this case I must finish typing the full word for the match to work.

Comment: As I mention above, you can customize it according to your needs. For substring match, you can change `return item[field] === word;` to `return item[field].indexOf(word) > -1;`.

Comment: Thanks, I very much like your solution... didn't even imagined it was possible without for loop. I think I understand what your code is supposed to do, except that indexOf can't be called on item[field] ?!

Comment: Got it: because sometimes there is no existing value for item[field] I added an if statement to return only if there is a value, else false, not sure if the false is require though. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Just some thing I don't understand here: every() and some() are supposed to return true or false values... by what magic does allMatch actually contains the desired entire objects ? Is it angularjs at work here ? Or something I don't get from JS ?

Comment: Indeed `some()` and `every()` return boolean values. `allMatch` is a boolean (it does not contain any item). The way the `filter` filter is implemented, `mySearch()` is a predicate function, which means that all items in the unfiltered array are passed throught the `mySearch()` function and the items for which the function returns `false` are filtered out. So, `mySearch()` needs to be a function that takes one `item` as input and return true if the item should be included in the output list or false otherwise. Angular takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.mySearch = function (item)
{
    var searchTerms = ["word1","word2"];
    var fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'phone', 'fax', 'category', 'subCat', 'company', 'street', 'zip', 'state', 'city', 'country'];

    for(var i = 0, l = searchTerm.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        if(fields.indexOf(searchTerms[i]) > -1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```